# Overriding Emacs 23 font substitutions

Tags: emacs, fonts

I use emacs with org-mode and other packages that assume all characters have the same width. This was not problematic until I started using Emacs 23 (on Mac and Linux) instead of Carbon Emacs. Now many non-ASCII characters (such as the phonetic characters in 0250–02AF) are rendered with a different font with different metrics. I would like to force emacs to render these characters with the same font as ASCII characters, e.g. DejaVu Sans Mono 10. How can this be achieved? Where is the documentation relating to emacs fonts in never versions located?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(set-fontset-font
 nil '(#x0250 . #x02af) (font-spec :family "DejaVu Sans Mono"))
```

Comment: That did it, and answered exactly the question I asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can move the cursor (point) over the phonetic character and do a `C-u C-x =` to run some version of `what-cursor-position`. This will open another buffer containing information about what is under the cursor - including a line containing `face` and a descriptionof what face is used. Remeber the name of the face used.

Then, call `M-x customize-face` and enter the remembered used face and customize it to your needs.

Comment: It's good to know about `what-cursor-position`. However, when I execute `what-cursor-position`, I don't get a `face` field. Weirdly, though, the category field says: `category: .:Base, j:Japanese, l:Latin`

Comment: It seems weird, but the "category" is related to iso2022 (and old Emacs mule encoding), so the appearance in there of "japanese" just means that it the character is supported by the japanese variant of iso2022, not that it is specifically a Japanese character.